# GetIDsOfNames implementation

Tags: c++, com

I need to implement GetIDsOfNames in my C++ application and I have no idea how to do that. 
I understand that I should implement GetTypeInfo, GetTypeInfoCount for that. I found a code sample which uses LIBID, but I don't have LIBID, and I don't know where to get one.

What I really need is a good explanation of IDispatch interface internals...

Answer (score 1):

Check the [OLE Automation Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237568(PROT.10).aspx)

Comment: As to GetTypeInfo, GetTypeInfoCount, why these functions are required, where are those type information used?

Comment: Required for late binding languages like VB or javascript. Do you want to support these languages?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good explanation of `IDispatch` internals, but if you have an .idl file for your interfaces you can generate a type library and include the latter into the COM server, then just use [`IDispatchImpl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494h01te(VS.80).aspx) than will do the work for you.